# TableLayout how to set android:layout_column dynamically?

Tags: android, tablelayout

I have TableLayout which is filled dynamically into code.

But after set new rows I have new rows different then head row, and header row itself is moved to right. Looks like there is null 1st column into head row:

Before adding rows (as I want it be always!):
[image]

After adding:
[image]

The red one - it's actually a field which has a null string inside

```
TextView.setText(null);
```

could this be a reason?

But anyway, I think I can fix it if I can set

```
android:layout_column
```

for new adding columns.

How can I do this right into code?

layout_column attributes are already set for header.

**Strange solution:**

header row are every time copied from existing "empty" table.

Then all entries removed.

Then add saved header, and then add new rows + empty View as 1st column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your .xml file code, in your head row if you put any textview which contain the null value as the first element of the head row then it will move right when you add another row by code in that tablelayout.

so, remove that textview which contain null value which are putting first element of the head row,

it may be solve your problem.

Comment: I have 4 views on each row. In header and in adding rows. Why should I put 5th view somewhere?

Comment: i just tell you that if you put any textview which containing null value as the first view of the header row then remove it,but if not then no need to remove, it is just a suggetion